# Is there an equivalent WPF's Visibility.Hidden property in UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, user-interface, uwp, winui

From [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.visibility?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=windowsdesktop-7.0&viewFallbackFrom=dotnet-uwp-10.0) in WPF the `Visibility` enum has three values, `Visible`, `Hidden`, `Collapsed`.

UWP is missing the `Hidden` property, which hides a control, but the space for that control is reserved.

Is there an equivalent WPF's Visibility.Hidden property in UWP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In UWP, there is no direct hidden function like what you did in WPF. A possible way is to use the [UIElement.Opacity Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.opacity?view=winrt-22621). You could set the Opacity as 0.

But remember that the control is still able to response to the user since it is not really hiding. So you need to set the **IsEnabled** property to `false` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [IsVisible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.isvisible?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) property?
Another solution is to use an [Opacity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.opacity?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) property.

Comment: Seems like the `IsVisible` property isn't present in UWP for elements either.

Comment: @Gabboxl You need to change opacity to 0 and set IsEnabled to false to achieve similar behavior like I mentioned in my answer